# How to keep the style tag from template HTML when using Preact Build?

Tags: css, webpack, preact

I am using Preact 3.0. I have a few `style` tags in the template index.html file. The purpose is to it keep it during building.
For example,

```
<style id="keep-this-tag">
  some-styles-that-should-not-be-put-in-style.css-file
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the tags themselves to stick around?

If so, just use the following config, or add to your existing:

```js
// preact.config.js

export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    const critters = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'Critters')[0];
    if (critters) {
        critters.plugin.options.mergeStylesheets = false;
    }
}
```

Critters is used for critical CSS inlining and, by default, it merges your style tags together. Easily disabled though, hope this helps.

Edit: With prerendering disabled, Critters will strip all CSS, as it's all thought to be "unused". To disable Critters, you can use the `--no-inline-css` flag, i.e., `preact build --no-inline-css`.

You do lose out on the inlining, but there's no way around it.

Comment: Hi @rschristian, thanks for your help. It looks very promising. I have just tried this. However, it did NOT solve the problem. I don't where I have got it wrong. Here is the pull request that contains your suggested solution. https://github.com/ZenUml/web-sequence/pull/361/files

Comment: It seems that it filters out some styles such as https://github.com/ZenUml/web-sequence/blob/e1db17a8dd3b485342a9768419f63ed66eb577a0/src/index.html#L62-L72. Maybe it is caused by another plugin?

Comment: Ah, you've disabled prerendering, that changes things a bit. What you can do is add a second line in that if statement, `critters.plugin.options.compress = false;`. Critters will remove unnecessary CSS rules if compression is enabled, and seeing as how you've disabled prerendering, there is no HTML for it to match against so everything is "unnecessary" and stripped out. So if you disable compression, extra rules will remain, and `mergeStylesheets` will just ensure those tags don't get merged into one big one. I'll also comment on that PR.

Comment: It has improved. For example, it has kept one `style` tag and the comment in that tag. But it has removed all the content. https://github.com/ZenUml/web-sequence/blob/4ece9e57d51abd6c6f628982ce7eebf8d2829fcc/src/index.html#L24-L37

Comment: Apologies, guess I was mistaken. It seems your only option is to disable critters entirely with `preact build ... --no-inline-css`. You can remove that config, it won't help.

Comment: It works now! Would you like to update your answer so it is easier for other people to find it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it, updated answer.